# App Badge not showing with Parse Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, badge

I am using Parse as my backend for my iOS app to send push notifications. My problem is that the app icon never shows a badge after receiving push notifications (Besides for the badge, everything works fine).

I've checked the "badge" field in the Installation DB on Parse and it is increasing with every push, so I feel it might be a client-side issue

Here is my cloud code:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
        aps: {
            alert: "Your friend " + request.user.get("Name") + " just joined VoiceMe!",
            sound: "default",
            AlertType: "NewFriend"
        },
        badge: "Increment"
    }
}, {
    success: function() {
        /*all is good*/
    },
    error: function(error) {
        outcome = false;
        errorOutput = error;
    }
});
```

And the code in my app:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        currentInstallation.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!, forKey: kParseInstallationUserKey)
    }
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.channels = ["global"]
    currentInstallation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (resultBool, error) -> Void in
        println("register device: --- \(resultBool) ---- error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Image of Installation DB on Parse:
[image]

Comment: Badge needs to go in the aps dictionary block. Not outside of it

Comment: I tried putting it outside of the aps dictionary but then it was not incrementing the badge count in the Installation DB?

Comment: That's why I said it goes inside

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I tried putting it inside and it wasn't increasing the badge count, that's why I put it outside

Comment: Then just put it in the data dictionary you don't need aps. I think your confused with APS and aps.

Comment: It is already in the data dictionary?

Comment: Yes but you've created your own dictionary called aps. Delete it and just put the payload into data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27615528/2353523 for reference

you've created your own dictionary. That's used for interactive notifications etc. Badge is outside of that dictionary that you've created which is the *correct* dictionary for sending pushes. That's why it doesn't increment in the payload you created under the dictionary of aps. You have to tell it to. Else, just delete the aps dict and pass your parameters through the data dict